# Quartz CronTrigger fails

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression, crontrigger

Hi I have created a cron job and its working well by using

```
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean
```

but when I schedule my job using CronTrigger the job didnt trigger at all neither it throw any error below is my spring config and Job class.

```
<bean id="cronJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runBillingJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
</bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="runTestJob" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronJobTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

following is my Test method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    List<JobExecutionContext> jobs = null;
    try {
        jobs = context.getScheduler().getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
        for (JobExecutionContext job : jobs) {
            if (job.getTrigger().equals(context.getTrigger())
                    && !job.getJobInstance().equals(this)) {
                logger.trace("There's another instance running, so leaving: "
                        + this);
                return;
            }
        }
        logger.info("Create a BillingService instance...");

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        logger.error("", e);
        return;
    }

    try {
        triggerToController();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I assume you have invoked start on SchedulerFactoryBean and waited until midnight for your cron expression to trigger?

Comment: You have a reference to runBillingJob but I cannot see where it is defined. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <bean id="cronJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runBillingJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="runBillingJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="your.package.YourClass" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronJobTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```